# Does the LTS hardware-enablement stack (HWE) contain all regular kernel updates?

Tags: kernel, updates, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

The official sources explain the HWE-kernel just as backporting support for newer hardware devices to older LTS releases.

But do the HWE-kernels only contain driver/module updates or also all other regular kernel updates for that specific minor version as well (e.g. native filesystem feature-updates, cryptographic updates, etc.)?

Comment: This kind of answers the question, but where do you find this actual information on the site? Besides for the fact that there is no mention of the 18.10 kernel version (probably because the graphics were created before that release), it does not specifically state that the kernel versions are the same. The differences between "general availability" and "hardware enablement" are not defined at all and the naming can be misinterpreted.

Comment: No problem. I was relatively sure to have understood that "HWE kernels are just regular kernels", but the fact that they are named differently and not knowing what's happening in the background made me uncertain, the documentation doesn't *really* clear this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HWE Kernels are not actually *backporting* features onto an older kernel.

Instead, HWE Kernels push LTS users onto *newer* kernels that are already in-use by a 6-month release of Ubuntu.

For example:

- Ubuntu 18.04 *without* HWE: Kernel 4.15.0
- Ubuntu 19.10: Kernel 5.3.0
- Ubuntu 18.04.4 *with* HWE: Kernel 5.3.0 (same as Ubuntu 19.10)
- Ubuntu 20.04: Kernel 5.4.0
- Ubuntu 18.04.5 *with* HWE (available July 2020): Kernel 5.4.0 (same as Ubuntu 20.04)

Only the most recent LTS Release gets HWE:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 (July 2020) will be the final HWE upgrade for 18.04. 18.04.5 will remain on 5.4.0 for the remainder of it's life. There won't be an 18.04.6.
- 20.04 LTS (Kernel 5.4.0) will begin the HWE cycle with 20.04.2 in January 2021, using the 20.10 kernel. The final HWE release will be 20.04.5 in July 2022.
- Since each LTS is on a two-year cycle, it's easy to keep track of which LTS is getting HWE, and when it will be retired in favor of the next LTS.

HWE upgrade occurs in January/July, approximately three months after the Interim Releases in April/October. You can easily identify the new HWE kernel by simply looking at the most recent Interim Release kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understood your question, yes. The HWE kernels will include features from newer kernels in regards to device support, filesystem changes/fixes, performance improvements, and more. That being said, you'll likely not be seeing things from a 5.8 kernel if the HWE kernel is 5.6. However, as time goes on and newer kernel series are brought into your Ubuntu release, such as 5.4 to 5.5, you will be receiving all of the new benefits of the 5.5 kernel, yes. This generally means improved compatibility and support for newer hardware, and potentially improved performance overall.

BTW, when it comes to security updates, these things are typically patched regardless of whether it's an HWE kernel or not (assuming it's a current release that's in-support, and not an out-of-support kernel or one that isn't in-line with your release, such as kernels installed from the mainline repos.)